# CSRF in Play 2.2.1 Scala always failing when csrf.sign.tokens is enabled

Tags: scala, csrf, playframework-2.2

Just upgrading to 2.2.1 and I'm a bit confused about what's going on with the CSRF handling. With the default config I always get "Missing CSRF token" errors, even though there's clearly a csrfToken in session data.

With a bit more poking around I found I could prevent this by setting `csrf.sign.tokens` to false in the settings (default is true). For some reason the lines:

```
token.flatMap(Crypto.extractSignedToken)
    .map(token => Token(Crypto.signToken(token)))
```

in [`CSRF.getToken`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-filters-helpers/src/main/scala/play/filters/csrf/csrf.scala#L76) is giving me a None token. Does anyone know what would make CSRF fail *only* when token signing is enabled. I have not (knowingly) changed any of the CSRF-related config defaults. My suspicion is that somehow the token is in the wrong format and [`Crypto.extractSignedToken`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/Crypto.scala#L90) is failing, but I can't figure out why this would be the case.

CSRF protection for my application is done using the global `WithFilters(CSRFFilter())` method.

Comment: I am having the same problem.  I can't manually reproduce the error but receive a few error reports daily.  Any updates Mike?  Thanks for posting.

Comment: Sorry Randy, I still haven't had time to revisit this and am still using unsigned tokens. I'll provide an answer here if I figure it out though.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  I switched to unsigned tokens and still get the error.  For me it only happens on public facing forms.

Comment: @RandyFindley still haven't diagnosed this properly but I notice as of Play 2.2.2-RC1 I no longer need to disable signed tokens. This doesn't help you of course, but I might poke around to see what changes have been made that might point to a culprit somewhere. If you're not yet on 2.2.2-RC1, it could be worth giving that a try (I've found no issues - although, be warned, **2.2.2-RC2** breaks incremental compilation for sub-projects completely.)

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be because CSRF tokens in Play 2.1.x aren't compatible with those in 2.2 or 2.3. If you have a cookie from a 2.1.x application and then upgrade the application to 2.2 you can see this issue when clients make a request with the old cookie value. The easiest solution I found was to rename the token in application.conf as follows:

```
csrf.token.name=csrfToken1
```

Bit of a nasty hack, but it works. I thought about moving the token to it's own cookie (using the `csrf.cookie.name` property but that still resulted in a "Missing CSRF Token" error

Comment: This is obvious when you look at the token values - in 2.1.x they are 20 characters whereas in 2.3 they are ~76